# newbie sinatra question

Tags: ruby, file, sinatra

To return a file using sinatra, I had been using this:

```
  get '/:name' do
    x = File.open('c:/mywebsite/' + params[:name],'r')
  end
```

where the incoming url is "http://localserver:4567/myfile.html.

It works, but it occurs to me there must be a better way, yet I can't find the preferred mechanism on the sinatra site.

Comment: Ah, THAT'S what "static files" means! ;)  Thanks, statenjason and mipadi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put static files in the public/ folder within the app's directory

> **Static Files**
>
> Static files are served from the
>   ./public directory. You can specify a
>   different location by setting the
>   :public option:
>
> set :public, File.dirname(`__FILE__`)
>   + '/static'
>
> Note that the public directory name is
>   not included in the URL. A file
>   ./public/css/style.css is made
>   available as
>   example.com/css/style.css.

from:
http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

Answer (score 2):

Is this a static file? If so, I'd put it in the application's `public` directory. You can read more about static files [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) (scroll about a quarter of the way down the page to find the section marked "Static Files").